# Filling the table in a loop

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, loops

How to fill a table in the loop?
I have an array of values, and I want to automatically fill in the table.

```
         <table>
       <thead>
            <tr>
      <div ng-repeat="n in range" >
                <th> {{vm.data.list[n].temp.day}} {{vm.symbal}}
            {{vm.data.list[n].humidity}} %
     </th>
      <div>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        </tr>
     </table>
```

And script:

```
       var range = [];
       for(var i=0;i<7;i++) {
         range.push(i);
       }
       $scope.range = range;
```

Comment: you have a typo in your ng-repeat. Should be 'range' not 'renge'

Comment: now in real code always "range"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need to create a range array, just iterate your list:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Day temp</th>
    <th>Symbal</th>
    <th>Humidity</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.data.list">
    <td ng-bind="item.temp.day"></td>
    <td ng-bind="vm.symbal"></td>
    <td ng-bind-template="{{ item.humidity }} %"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/PeTrMWJIBjXLegOQ1wRx?p=preview